# How does a container component update its child component through react redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, react-redux

Looking at the [reddit example](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html) off of the react redux docs, I'm having difficulty see how the posts list component updates itself based on the state of the picker changing. Is it through the `componentWillReceiveProps` life cycle method in the container method that's causing this? This is how I see the flow of data and state change:

1. user selected reddit
2. store state is changed
3. store is props of container component, so in effect it's props is changed
4. componentWillReceiveProps is triggered and dispatches fetchPostsIfNeeded
5. posts list is changed

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Redux example connects the AsyncApp container and its children, the Picker & Posts components, to the Redux store via the [react-redux libraries `connect` method](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options). The connect method takes a mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps functions to enable the container to pass the redux state and actions to the child components as props.

Now the child component has access to those props eg. `const { selectedSubreddit, posts, isFetching, lastUpdated } = this.props`. And it can also dispatch those actions to update the redux store and that will in turn update those props it has connected to.

Redux is a way to manage your application state and it does not care about your UI or whether you use React. React-redux is a library that provides bindings from your React components to your Redux store.

Comment: So you're saying the list component will update itself because it's receiving props from the parent component who is connected to the store? What purpose then is the componentWillReceiveProps method serving?

Comment: The components render method will run again anytime the state/store updates any connected props, and yes the props on the component will update. componentWillReceiveProps is a React lifecycle method - you would typically use this method to make some other changes on the component before it re-renders. You really need to read the React docs, specifically: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html